# Filtrar datos entre fechas - Python

Tags: python, date

Amigos, necesito crear nuevos dataframe's según condiciones de fechas.

Ejemplo 1:

Filtrar todos los datos de las personas que estaban activas en el año 2018. Son aquellas que fueron dadas de alta hasta el 31/12/2018 y fueron dadas de baja con posterioridad a esta fecha.

Mi dataframe es el siguiente:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Nombres']= ['Juana','Luisa','Pedro']
df['Fecha_Nac'] = ['26/03/1944','12/07/1965','01/08/2001']
df['Fecha_alta'] = ['01/01/2018','2/10/2015','03/03/2021']
df['Fecha_baja'] = ['01/02/2018', '2/10/17','14/03/2020']
df
```

Lo que he intentado realizar es lo siguiente:

```
Fecha_Inicio_2018 = datetime(2018, 1, 1)
Fecha_Fin_2018 = datetime(2018, 1, 1)
filtered_df=df.query("Fecha_alta <= 'Fecha_Fin_2018' and Fecha_baja >= 'Fecha_Fin_2018'")
filtered_df
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes hacer es convertir las columnas de fecha que son strings a formato datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Nombres'] = ['Juana','Luisa','Pedro']
df['Fecha_Nac'] =['26/03/1944','12/07/1965','01/08/2001']
df['Fecha_alta'] = ['01/01/2018','2/10/2015','03/03/2021']
df['Fecha_baja'] = ['01/02/2018','2/10/17','14/03/2020']


df['Fecha_Alta'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_alta'],format ='%d/%m/%Y',errors='coerce')
df['Fecha_Baja'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_baja'],format='%d/%m/%Y',errors='coerce')
```

La tabla resultante seria esta:

```
  Nombres   Fecha_Nac  Fecha_alta  Fecha_baja Fecha_Alta Fecha_Baja
  0   Juana  26/03/1944  01/01/2018  01/02/2018 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
  1   Luisa  12/07/1965   2/10/2015     2/10/17 2015-10-02        NaT
  2   Pedro  01/08/2001  03/03/2021  14/03/2020 2021-03-03 2020-03-14
```

el parametro **errors = 'coerce'** devuelve un tipo de dato llamato NaT cuando encuentra un error en el fortmato, tal es el caso de **2/10/17** ya que no es un formato de d/m/Y, en el caso de que la informacion llegue en ese formato se tendria que transformar manualmente

Ahora se puede aplicar el filtro de esta manera

```
filtered_df = df[(df['Fecha_Alta'] <=datetime.datetime(year=2018,month=12,day=31) & (df['Fecha_Baja'] >=datetime.datetime(year=2010,month=1,day=1))]
print(filtered_df)
```

Y el resultado del dataframe filtrado seria este:

```
    Nombres   Fecha_Nac  Fecha_alta  Fecha_baja Fecha_Alta Fecha_Baja
0   Juana    26/03/1944  01/01/2018  01/02/2018 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ahí lo probaré. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Probé con este código y ahí me funcionó, quizás ustedes tienen una forma más prolija de hacerlo:

```
filtered_df=df[(df['Fecha_alta'] <= '2018-12-31') & (df['Fecha_baja'] >= '2019-01-01')]
filtered_df
```

Saludos